# Plotly.Js not working IE. Error in vendor.js

Tags: typescript, plotly, vendor, plotly.js

Js in angular 6 application. Its working fine in `Chrome`, `Edge`, and `Firefox`. Its giving error in IE.

> SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier
>   vendor.js (290527,19)

On further debugging, it shows
error in vendor.js at

```
// get all points within the passed range
function range ( ...args ) {
    let options

    if (isObj(args[args.length - 1])) {
        let arg = args.pop()

        // detect if that was a rect object
        if (!args.length && (arg.x != null || arg.l != null || arg.left != null)) {
            args = [arg]
            options = {}
        }

        options = pick(arg, {
            level: 'level maxLevel',
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Plotly with webpack (which Angular CLI do internally) the ify-loader (Webpack loader to handle browserify transforms as intended.) plugin is required. I changed to using the @angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser builder and added this to the webpack config which solved it.

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loader: 'ify-loader'
    }]
  },
};
```

Comment: In which file did you add that code snippet https://stackoverflow.com/users/29906/jmw

Comment: The custom-webpack:broswer builder allows a file that is merged with the internal webpack config and it was in that file.
Since then we have moved away from this solution and are now using angular-plotly (npm) that made this workaround unnecessary for us.